# Linking accounts from 2 different simple membership applications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, simplemembership

So, I have two applications, each running their own MVC 4 Simple Membership databases. We now want to be able to link accounts across the applications so that info from one (call it Application B) can be pulled into the other (Application A).

There is a small subset of users who would have accounts in both applications.

We don't really want to go the OAuth route via external providers (Google, Facebook etc), but not really sure the best method to do this.

Ideally, it should be a one-time link between the accounts without needing to login each time.

Comment: You don't want to go OAuth for facebook, google, etc., but is having your own OAuth server a consideration? (Login to Site B from Site A through oauth)? Alternatively, you could create a secure connection between the two sites to exchange information, and in the login action you first check for credentials locally, then look remotely (through that tunnel) to pull a user in from the other site.

Comment: At this stage - yes, although we've no experience of OAuth at all.

Comment: I'd thought about logging in to A, then providing a view to login to B from within A - once successful, store user id from B in A, then secure connection idea works. But how do you login to B from A - you can only have one Simple Membership database connection as far as I'm aware? Can you do a "manual" login external to simple membership?